# Segmentaion fault calling method the second time C++

Tags: c++, methods, fault

If I add a second call to setColor I am getting a segmentation fault. I think maybe that method is changing the array pointer somehow, but I'm not sure why.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Color {
    int red;
    int blue;
    int green;
};

void setColor(Color **arr, int index, int red, int blue, int green) {
    Color *ptr = arr[index];
    (*ptr).red = red;
    (*ptr).blue = blue;
    (*ptr).green = green;
}

int main() { 
    Color *arr[3];
    setColor(arr, 0, 12, 23, 34);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want some actual *objects* behind those indeterminate pointers.

Comment: Why so many pointers? All those spiky stars hurt my eyes.

Comment: you are allocating memory for Color* (in arr) but not the target Color objects. I'm surprised this works even once.

Comment: You have to *assign* a variable a value before you *use* that value. You create a variable called `arr[0]` that has no particular value, then you attempt to use that value by dereferencing it. Not good.

Comment: These three pointers point to nowhere. Accessing data through them will lead to the undefined behaviour.

Comment: I modernised your code. http://ideone.com/65o4Ku

Comment: @Rapptz, And I simplified it :) http://ideone.com/d67xj5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared an array of pointers to colors but not set aside any memory for it to use. This is undefined behavior. Being undefined behavior, you can't say what's going to happen. If you keep running it, you might get a cup off coffee from it!

In an effort to make this answer worth keeping, the exact scenario you have illustrated is called dereferencing a [wild pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_wild_pointers).

Answer (score 6):

`arr` is an uninitialized array of pointers. You're "lucky" it works at all, because you invoked **undefined behaviour**.